# How to send a job to nodes of different types in SLURM

Tags: task, jobs, scheduling, slurm, hpc

I work at a HPC centre where we use SLURM to manage queues and I'm looking for a way to force a job divided by tasks to be sent to nodes of different types. For example, let's say we have two types of nodes called lpn and hpn, and we want a job to be divided into two tasks (under only one job ID) and get one of them sent to a lpn node and the other one, to a hpn node. Which one of each, it doesn't matter: it can be lpn-1 and hpn-36, lpn-47 and hpn-13... but it has to be each of one. This could also be more general.

I tried using the nodelist and contraint options, but none of them work for forcing the assignation of specific and different types of nodes. Any time the job was sent succesfully, both tasks just went to the same node. I'm starting to feel that this isn't possible due to SLURM's optimization system, but it's worth a try asking regardless.

Comment: can I just know your use case?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give you any, as I'm just a systems technician intern with few months of experience there and I don't know any of them. We're just testing this possibility. However, somebody gave me a hint on the problem on another answer, so we're gonna work through that now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to achieve what you want with [het jobs](https://slurm.schedmd.com/heterogeneous_jobs.html) with a submission script looking like

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --constraint=hpn
#SBATCH hetjob
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --constraint=lpn

srun <the command on the `hpn` node> : <the command on the `lpn` node>
```

assuming the nodes features are set accordingly. This should work as well if the different node types are in two distinct partitions, simply by replacing both `--constrain=` with `--partition`.

Note the `:` in the `srun` command to list the commands to run on each node. Alternatively, if you want two distinct steps you can replace the single `srun` line with :

```
srun --hetgroup 0 <the command on the `hpn` node> &
srun --hetgroup 1 <the command on the `lpn` node> &
wait
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work, but it gave us a hint on why this seems to be impossible in our cluster: as we had a "Jobs violate accounting/QoS policy" error message. My HPC center has been using SLURM for years and, as I can see, the hetjob option is relatively recent, so it wouldn't be strange that our configuration doesn't allow us to properly use hetjob with the purpose I'm working on, as it couldn't have been taken into account when SLURM was configured in the cluster. My superiors will check the QoS configuration. 

Thanks a lot!